# Mix of Google Fonts and Fontello not working in Safari

Tags: css, hyperlink, safari, icons, webfonts

I've recently noticed that links wrapped around Fontello icons are impossible to click on Safari 5.1.7 (or should I say "latest" Win realese"). I really don't know what could cause the issue (other browser are ok). I was trying to mess with web-inspector and unclik every custom style that could affect Fontello.

Is somebody aware of any Fontello/Safari incompatibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Took me long enough to realize that somehow Google Fonts are causing some sort of issue when set on a parent of "a" containig fontello icon.

For now there is one solution that I've found - "a" has to have extra

```
font-family: "fontello"
```

See my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Nippon/Qu6W5/

Is there other way around it?